# Trying to use eval to dynamically assign variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a bunch of variables in a Python script like this:

```
pauseTime = 10
cameraSrc = "rtsp://cameraadress"
useCuda = True
```

But I'm getting from an API the new values for this variables
and I'm trying to do the following:

```
for key,value in func.configJsonIot.items():
    if key == "debug":
        continue
    else:
        if debug:
            print("Sobrescrevendo valores locais pelos da API key: {} | value: {}".format(key, value))
        eval(str(key)) = value
```

this is returning me this error:

```
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call
```

How can I change the global variables with the API values?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using a dictionary? Then you can do `var_dict = {}; var_dict["useCuda"] = False; print(var_dict["useCuda"])`.

Comment: The proposed duplicate is not just indirectly on-point; it has answers describing the same `globals()` practice the OP's own answer uses.

Answer (score 0):

assign a variable to the function and then use that in the for loop.

so

```
json_items = func.confJsonIot.items()
```

then

```
for key,value in json_items: ...
```

this will give you a dict called `json_items` that you can use in the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution for this:

```
for key,value in func.configJsonIot.items():
    if key == "debug":
        continue
    else:
        if debug:
            print("Sobrescrevendo valores locais pelos da API key: {} | value: {}".format(key, value))
        globals()[key]=value
```

`globals()` function can acess all global variables running

Comment: Why do you need to use `globals()`? You already have all `key: value` pairs in `func.configJsonIot`...

Comment: becouse a need to overhide the already generated in hardcode and already in use vars while my code is running acordinh to API result

Comment: Put your variables in a dict from the first place and then update the dict...

Comment: yes but i cannot change the entire code right now :(

Comment: at total i need to overhide 135 variables :( the system is huge

Comment: So? What's the difference if they are variables or inside a dict? It's not a big enough difference. `135` variables is really not that much...

Comment: i agree but i need to change to many files and big part of then i cannot modify